# how to get two or more array data from php page to javascript using json

Tags: javascript, php, json

The code below is in `EAddEmployeeAddAndOtherParts.php` page:

```
$array1 = array("i am first array");
$array2 = array("i am second array");
echo json_encode($array1,$array2);
```

The code below is in the `home.html` page:

```
$(document).ready( function() {     
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'EAddEmployeeAddAndOtherParts.php',
        data: 'aa='+aa+'&f='+f,
        dataType: 'html',
        cache: false,
        success: function(result1,result2) {

alert(result1[0]);
alert(result2[0]);
        },          
    });
});
```

My question is: How can I get `$array1` and `$array2` data in my `home.html` page using JSON? My code above is not working.

Comment: json_encode< http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php > get an array not two arrays

Comment: [RTFM](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php) :D

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is solved by reading the documentation

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [`json_encode()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php) only uses the first argument as the data, so wrap your two arrays into a single array:

```
echo json_encode(array('array1' => $array1, 'array2' => $array2));
```

In the ajax call, the response is the first argument, and because in the above, we used keys, we can directly reference `result.array1`. So change to

```
dataType: 'json',
success: function(result) {
    alert(result.array1);
    alert(result.array2);
},
```

Also note, I changed the dataType to `json`. If you continue to use `html` as the dataType, then jQuery won't automatically parse the JSON for you.

Answer (score 1):

```
header('Content-type:application/json');
echo json_encode(array($array1,$array2));
exit;
```